# Group list items according to digit counts in second list

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, graph

The goal is to create a stacked bar graph showing the sentiment of tweets (that I got from tweepy) over a total of 360 seconds (by second). I have two lists. The first one has the sentiment analysis of the tweets in chronological order and the second one has the amount of tweets per second, also in chronological order.

```
list1 = ("neg", "pos", "pos", "neu", "neg", "pos", "neu", "neu",...)
list2 = (2, 1, 3, 2,...)
```

Now I would like to create some sort of nested loop and use list2 to count the items in list 1. I would then have 3 lists with 360 values for each sentiment that I can use for the graph. Its should give me an output similar to this:

```
lis_negative = (1, 0, 1, 0, ...)
lis_positive = (1, 1, 1, 0, ...)
lis_neutral = (0, 0, 1, 2, ...)
```

How can I create this loop and is there maybe a simpler approach to it? I would prefer not to use any library for it other than matplotlib.

Comment: *use list2 to count the items in list 1* What does that mean?

Comment: Ah, I think I understood now.

Comment: @timgeb `list2` is a count of how many tweets where saved per minute. So to know how many pos/neg/neu tweets were saved per second I need `list2`

Comment: Since `list2` means 2 tweets at 1st second that means 1st two values in `list1`. Hence the output desired from OP shows 1 and 1 in pos and neg lists

Comment: Gotcha, I think I can come up with an algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import Counter

def categorize(clas, amounts):
    cats = {'neg': [], 'pos': [], 'neu': []}
    clas = iter(clas)

    for a in amounts:
        cs = Counter(islice(clas, a)) # take a items
        for cat in cats:
            cats[cat].append(cs[cat])
    return cats
```

Demo:

```
>>> t1 = ('neg', 'pos', 'pos', 'neu', 'neg', 'pos', 'neu', 'neu')
>>> t2 =  (2, 1, 3, 2)
>>> 
>>> categorize(t1, t2)
{'neg': [1, 0, 1, 0], 'neu': [0, 0, 1, 2], 'pos': [1, 1, 1, 0]}
```

As requested, a solution without imports:

```
def make_counter(iterable):
    c = {}
    for x in iterable:
        c[x] = c.get(x, 0) + 1
    return c

def categorize(clas, amounts):
    cats = {'neg': [], 'pos': [], 'neu': []}
    pos = 0

    for a in amounts:
        chunk = clas[pos:pos+a]
        pos += a
        cs = make_counter(chunk)
        for cat in cats:
            cats[cat].append(cs.get(cat, 0))
    return cats
```

edit: shorter import-less solution:

```
def categorize(clas, amounts):
    cats = {k:[0]*len(amounts) for k in ('neg', 'pos', 'neu')}
    pos = 0

    for i, a in enumerate(amounts):
        chunk = clas[pos:pos+a]
        pos += a
        for c in chunk:
            cats[c][i] += 1

    return cats
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very neat. Is there a possibility to solve the problem without importing any library etc?  **Edit** Seeing that they are standard I will try this approach for my code. Thank you

Comment: @Aileen yes, but before I code a clunky implementation without using the standard library, would you tell me why?

Comment: This problem is part of a bigger uni assignment for which we are not allowed to use libraries other than matplotlib. That's why I was looking for an approach that uses simple for loops etc.

Comment: Yeah, but matplotlib imports strongly from the standard library (as well as using numpy).

Comment: @Aileen I see. I added an import-less solution.